# java on "server" linux: Is there any way to run in client mode?

Tags: java, linux, garbage-collection

I'm running a java web server as an internal component of another project, and unfortunately java insists on running in server mode (i.e. fast, and huge memory footprint), even when I pass the `-client` switch.

This is a problem because java takes up so much memory that my whole project is killed by the server.

I'm running java with the command:

```
java -client -classpath /home/marcintustin/webapps/django/oneclickcosvirt/oneclickcos/java:/home/marcintustin/webapps/django/oneclickcosvirt/oneclickcos/java/commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar:/home/marcintustin/webapps/django/oneclickcosvirt/oneclickcos/java/fop-20120125.jar:/home/marcintustin/webapps/django/oneclickcosvirt/oneclickcos/java/xmlgraphics-commons-1.5svn.jar:/home/marcintustin/webapps/django/oneclickcosvirt/oneclickcos/java/batik-all.jar:/home/marcintustin/webapps/django/oneclickcosvirt/oneclickcos/java/docx4j-nightly-20120105.jar:/home/marcintustin/webapps/django/oneclickcosvirt/oneclickcos/java/spark-0.9.9.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/marcintustin/webapps/django/oneclickcosvirt/oneclickcos/java/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/home/marcintustin/webapps/django/oneclickcosvirt/oneclickcos/java/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/home/marcintustin/webapps/django/oneclickcosvirt/oneclickcos/java/jetty-webapp-7.3.0.v20110203.jar:/home/marcintustin/webapps/django/oneclickcosvirt/oneclickcos/java/servlet-api-3.0.pre4.jar:/home/marcintustin/webapps/django/oneclickcosvirt/oneclickcos/java/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/home/marcintustin/webapps/django/oneclickcosvirt/oneclickcos/java/commons-codec-1.6.jar:/home/marcintustin/webapps/django/oneclickcosvirt/oneclickcos/java/docx4j-2.7.1.jar:/home/marcintustin/webapps/django/oneclickcosvirt/oneclickcos/java/poi-scratchpad-3.8-beta4.jar:/home/marcintustin/webapps/django/oneclickcosvirt/oneclickcos/java/xalan-2.7.1.jar:/home/marcintustin/webapps/django/oneclickcosvirt/oneclickcos/java/antlr-runtime-3.3.jar:/home/marcintustin/webapps/django/oneclickcosvirt/oneclickcos/java/commons-io-2.1.jar:/home/marcintustin/webapps/django/oneclickcosvirt/oneclickcos/java/serializer-2.7.1.jar:/home/marcintustin/webapps/django/oneclickcosvirt/oneclickcos/java/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar:/home/marcintustin/webapps/django/oneclickcosvirt/oneclickcos/java/avalon-framework-api-4.3.1.jar:/home/marcintustin/webapps/django/oneclickcosvirt/oneclickcos/java/commons-lang-2.4.jar:/home/marcintustin/webapps/django/oneclickcosvirt/oneclickcos/java/log4j-1.2.15.jar:/home/marcintustin/webapps/django/oneclickcosvirt/oneclickcos/java/stringtemplate-3.2.1.jar:/home/marcintustin/webapps/django/oneclickcosvirt/oneclickcos/java/avalon-framework-impl-4.3.1.jar:/home/marcintustin/webapps/django/oneclickcosvirt/oneclickcos/java/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/home/marcintustin/webapps/django/oneclickcosvirt/oneclickcos/java/poi-3.8-beta4.jar:/home/marcintustin/webapps/django/oneclickcosvirt/oneclickcos/java/wmf2svg-0.9.0.jar: Transcoder
```

`java -version` reports:

```
java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-b147)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0-b17, mixed mode)
```

As I'm on a shared host, I can't install 32-bit compatibility libraries, so I can't use the 32-bit JRE. This turns out to be a problem because as confirmed by @birryree in the comments (thanks!), 64-bit JRE always runs in server mode.

**Is there a way to force java to run in normal client mode?**

Comment: What if you explicitly specify the memory allocation with `-X` command parameters?

Comment: How do you know it's running on server mode when you specify the -client parameter?

Comment: @theglauber It runs quickly, and with the huge memory footprint it has when run anywhere in server mode, rather than the much smaller footprint that it has in client mode (on windows).

Comment: The client VM should only save you a few tens of MB.  If this is making such a ciritcal difference, shouldn't you be using a larger server?

Comment: @AleksG I don't know. The help output doesn't list a `-X` flag.

Comment: @PeterLawrey The difference is about a factor of 10.

Comment: In that case, it has nothing to do with running client vs server mode. Have you tried running with a more up to date JVM. If you have a 64-bit machine this will use 32-bit references by default, but this will only make a difference of up to 30%.

Comment: @PeterLawrey As I say, running with `-server` on windows leads to the same memory footprint as on my shared host; running with `-client` leads to about a tenth of the memory usage. So I would say that, yes, running in server mode is a part of this issue.

Comment: Server mode will use a percentage of your main memory size as a maximum. e.g. 1/4. Try setting a lower maximum memory size. BTW for the client vm its usually 64 or 128 MB.

Comment: Can you provide an example of some code which does this because I find it very hard to believe? (And I have been developing Java systems for 12 years)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Hang on, that was the wrong java version. I've now updated my question with the correct version.

Comment: Hmmmm, it could be a bug given its update 0, can you try update 3?

Comment: How much memory do you have on your server?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Physically, loads, but I am restricted to 512Mb.

Comment: 64-bit Server JREs ignore the `-client` flag and will run in the default `-server` configuration. Can you try passing the `-d32` flag as well to run the JVM in 32-bit mode? You might also have to get a 32-bit Java.

Comment: @birryree It refuses to start in 32-bit mode (setting that flag just results in an error message). I'll install a 32bit jre.

Comment: @birryree Unfortunately the 32 bit java distribution won't run on a 64-bit system :( Looks like I'm stuck with setting memory limits.

Comment: That's strange, @Marcin - the 32-bit JVM definitely runs on a 64-bit system.

Comment: @birryree There seems to be an issue with loading shared libraries.

Comment: You'll need to install 32-bit compatibility libraries - the method to do so depends on what linux distribution you're running.

Comment: @birryree It's a shared host, so that's a non-starter, unfortunately. If you want to write an answer on the lines of the advice you've given me, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments received (and testing), it seems that the 64bit JVM ALWAYS runs in server mode, which means that it is VERY profligate with memory.

The work-arounds are:

1. Get the 32bit JVM (and appropriate compatibility libraries if on Linux); or
2. Use the -X options to limit memory to a certain maximum.